# composer update -- how to skip updating dependencies when updating single package

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use Composer to update a single package without updating any dependencies.

I run this:

```
composer update -vv {package_name}
```

where `{package_name}` is a package in a private repository (git repo) that contains a composer.json with **zero** dependencies.

However, when I run this, it hangs for quite some time on `Updating dependencies`, and then it reports:

```
Analyzed 18068 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 451772 rules to resolve dependencies
```

How do I get Composer to stop doing that? I want to update {package_name} and recreate the autoload files, but not update any dependencies. I checked the [options in the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u), but didn't see what I was looking for.

(to be clear, I'm mostly concerned about speed here, I want to update my package quickly)

Comment: You can always put in a fixed version, for those resources if you don't want to update them.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Right now Composer refreshes and loads all packages info before any update command (you can see what is happening using `-vvv` switch), and this is probably main bottleneck in your case. Although this could be skipped in your case, I doubt that anyone will complicate Composer code to handle such exception.

Comment: But if you really need it and you're sure that updating this package will not touch anything else, you can write your own script which will replace commit hash in `composer.lock` and then call `composer install` - it is hack, but is should work in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to first add {{packagename}} to the composer.json file. Then perform the following:

```
composer update {{packagename}} --lock
```

Hope my answer works for you.